# How to get name and author of android apk file using python?

Tags: android

I'm doing some reverse engineering work on android apk files. And I use androgurad to help me resolve apk, but it seems that I cannot get the name and author information through the APIs provided by androGuard. Though the resource id can be got by resolving androidManifest.xml, but there is no way to get resource value by id. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ApkTool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) to get all related information about resources and IDs.